# Delete rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am new with Power BI and in my dataset I would like to delete some rows. The rows I want to delete have got an ID. However, these indices do not correspond with the row numbers (Row_nr). Basically my data looks like this:

[image: Indication of my data]

I would like to delete the rows where ID = 7, 14, 16 and 19 (for example, the dataset I use is much bigger) How can I do this in Power BI?

Comment: Could you provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least the code you have ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. In both cases, edit the data query.

1.) You can filter the data, i.e. select the column filter drop-down, then untick the values you don't want to include.

2.) Or you can create a calculated column with a formula that looks at the ID column and returns a flag, like "keep" or "delete". In the formula you can construct a more complex logic than in the direct filter. The details for that formula will depend on your business logic. Then, in the next step, filter by that helper column and select only "keep". After that you can remove the helper column.